# Is There Any Reason To Sign Message Bodies When You Are Using Mutual SSL with a Client Certificate

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, ssl

I've recently had to implement XML messaging with two large entities that required us to provide an SSL client certificate as well as sign the SOAP message body with a different signing certificate.  Aside from redundancy, does the signing of the message body **WITH A DIFFERENT CERTIFICATE** provide any additional protection?

Edited to provide clarification of the question and point out the years-long misunderstanding between myself and EJP.

The value of signing the message in addition to using SSL with mutual auth (client cert) is that you get non-repudiation.  However, you get that whether or not the client cert is used to sign the message or a different signing cert is used.

Comment: Is the SOAP message signed with a different key than the SSL certificate? How does each side know the other side's keys are trusted?

Comment: The same way you know the server's cert is trusted without mutual auth, via CAs and sub-CAs.

Comment: OK, I misread your question. If the certificate being used is *different*, then it's not totally redundant. Also, is the SOAP message ever used outside the context of the SSL session? Perhaps there is an SSL load balancer to validate the initial request, but the back-end servers also need to validate the message? Otherwise, if an attacker can get in between the SSL load balancer and the back-end server, they can do a man-in-the-middle attack with unauthenticated SOAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signing the message provides legally enforceable non-repudiation over the transaction. You have proof that that client and only that client could have sent that message, and you can repeat the signature verification in court to demonstrate. SSL gives you the same thing technically at a lower level, but you don't have any way of getting the signature out, so you can't produce it in court: you are down to handwaving in evidence, as opposed to an actual digital signature, which is a legal signature and thus *prima facie* evidence.

Comment: This would still be true even if the same cert was used as the client cert for SSL and for signing, right?

Comment: @JohnOpincar You would still be unable to produce the actual signature.

Comment: I'm saying that all the benefits of signing the message would accrue even if I used the same certificate for both signing and authentication.

Comment: @JohnOpincar And I'm saying that you wouldn't be able to produce the actual digital signature in court.

Comment: If I signed the message body, why would I not be able to produce the actual signature in court just because I used the same cert for SSL mutual auth?  That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @JohnOpincar You baffle me.That is exactly my point. If you signed the message yourself, you would be able to prodiuce it in court. If you relied on SSL's undisclosed signatures you wouldn't. Whether you use the same certificate for both purposes, if that's possible, or two different certificates, has no bearing, and is not mentioned in my answer. You're agreeing with me, but you don't appear to realise it.

Comment: The key point to my question (which may not be clear), is that using a different cert for signing isn't necessary.  If you don't save the message, signing it is worthless for non-repudiation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I'd term it "protection", but those are two different things. SSL certificates serve to verify your identity for encryption/transmission purposes.

SOAP signing allows the end user to verify that the XML has not been altered since the creator (you) signed it.

Comment: I understand that.  But doesn't a client SSL cert achieve the same thing?  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication): "Mutual SSL provides the same things as SSL, with the addition of authentication and non-repudiation of the client authentication, using digital signatures."

Comment: if you edit your answer to explicitly point out that the signature proves it hasn't been altered on the receiver's side even after it's come off the transport layer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: In the case I'm working on, the signature is only applied to two timestamps in the header of the soap message.  So it still seems worthless.  But if the message body was actually signed, then it would definitely add value.

Comment: @JohnOpincar See my answer. Wiki wrong again? I don't believe that non-repudiation via SSL with client auth alone is legally sound. A digital signature is a legal signature but with SSL alone you cannot actually produce it.

Comment: EJP answered it well above. It's less about the functionality and more about the intent.

Answer (score 0):

With transport-layer security, your security ends at the transport layer. By signing the SOAP message, you are providing end-to-end authentication for the *application* layer.

Without the SSL client certificate, anyone on the internet can talk to your back-end servers. That increases your attack surface.

Without application-layer security, imagine what could happen if an attacker gained control of an SSL load balancer / reverse proxy. (They could send any SOAP message they want to your back-end server with no authentication?!)

So it seems like they both do provide some value, yes.

The other question I would ask is, how are the keys (that is, SSL client certificate and SOAP signing certificate) secured? If it's trivial for an attacker to gain control of both keys, that would diminish the returns of this approach.

By using a different key to sign SOAP messages than to authenticate your connection, you also open up more flexibility around how you do your PKI. For example, your network administration team might want to issue one SSL client certificate per organization, but the application team might want one SOAP message signing certificate per entity in that organization.

Comment: I have to have the private key for the client cert to initiate SSL mutual auth.  It's my understanding that the transport layer packets are signed using the client certificate.  So I don't see an issue if an attacker gained control of a load balancer / reverse proxy.  I do with plain old SSL but not when I'm using a client cert with SSL.

Comment: I agree that once the message comes off the transport it's vulnerable to tampering on the receiver's side.  So to me that's the real answer here.

Comment: Once you gain control of the reverse proxy, the theory is that you can talk "in the clear" to the back-end server. The SSL client certificate only protects the traffic between you and the proxy.